# C# WPF - Change column background color in code

Tags: c#, wpf

I've never really worked with WPF before so this might be a newb question but is there a way to change the background color of a column of a WPF grid?

I want to change column 0's background color from the code.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Banner" Width="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gainsboro" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gainsboro" />
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gainsboro" />
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gainsboro" />

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="titleLabel" 
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" 
           FontWeight="Bold"
           Content="Title" >

    </Label>
    <Label x:Name="msgLabel" 
           Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" 
           Content="Title" >
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Add one more border which covers that column, then change its background?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it per code?

Comment: @Evk is there a way to select all rows to do this? what were you thinking?

Comment: @cbutler Just set `Grid.RowSpan` on the `Border` element.  That'll make it occupy multiple rows.

Comment: The WPF way would be to bind to a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one more border and place it in first column (note RowSpan):

```
<Border x:Name="firstColumn" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.RowSpan="4" 
        Background="Transparent"/>
```

When need to change background from code, just do

```
firstColumn.Background = Brushes.Red;
```